# Unity Backface Culling not Deleting Unviewable Faces

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

My Unity Project appears to continue rendering faces that cannot be seen.

I'm creating a Minecraft clone, where there are many cubes:

[image]

Performance is very bad, and if you turn on wireframe mode you can see that it's rendering all faces, even covered ones and ones facing away from me:

[image]

I'm not sure if it matters, but in the block blender model, backface culling is enabled:

[image]

Additionally, the normals are facing outwards:
[image]

Occlusion Culling is enabled in Unity:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: i never looked that hard but you didnt mention turning on occulsion culling or using its visuliser,  That would help

Comment: Backface culling doesn't render faces that are turned away from the camera. All the faces of the cubes deep inside of your landscape still have faces that have their normals turned in the direction of the camera. All the boxes inside are rendered even though you cannot actually see them. To save on performance Minecraft takes chunks of cubes and coalesces them into big iragular shaped blocks that don't have any faces inside.